# Writing servlet using NuoDB

Tags: java, servlets, nuodb

I am novice in using `NuoDB`. I've a task to redo my `servlet-application` to it can use `NuoDB` data base.
So, this is my new doGet servlet method:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    //doPost(request, response);
    String outPage = "<h1>Output:</h1><br>";
    List<Info> list_cars = new ArrayList<Info>();

    try
    {
        //DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.nuodb.jdbc.Driver());
        Class.forName("com.nuodb.jdbc.Driver");
        DBWorker db = new DBWorker("dba", "goalie", "cars");
        list_cars = db.getUser();

    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list_cars.size(); i++)
    {
        outPage += "Car name: " + list_cars.get(i).getCarName() + "<br>";
        outPage += "Car color" + list_cars.get(i).getCarColor() + "<br>";
        outPage += "Car size: " + list_cars.get(i).getCarSize().toString() + "<br>";
        outPage += "Car release: " + list_cars.get(i).getCarRelease().toString() + "<br>";            
        outPage += "-------------<br>";
    }

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("data", outPage);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String res = Templater.view("results", map);
    out.println(res);                   
}
```

This is my class which works with dataBase:

```
public class DBWorker 
{
    /**
     * The driver class provided by NuoDB.
     */
    public static final String DRIVER_CLASS = "com.nuodb.jdbc.Driver";
    /**
     * The base URL for connecting to a local database server.
     */
    public static final String DATABASE_URL =
            "jdbc:com.nuodb://localhost:8080/";
    // the established connection to a local server
    private Connection dbConnection;

    public DBWorker(String user, String password, String dbName) throws SQLException
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("user", user);
        properties.put("password", password);
        properties.put("schema", "HOCKEY");
        dbConnection =  DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL + dbName, properties);
    }

    public void insertUser(String name, String color, Integer size, Date release) throws SQLException
    {
        PreparedStatement stmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement("insert into CARS (CAR_NAME, CAR_COLOR, CAR_SIZE, CAR_RELEASE) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");

        try
        {
            stmt.setString(1, name);
            stmt.setString(2, color);
            stmt.setInt(3, size);
            stmt.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(release.getTime()));
            stmt.addBatch();
            stmt.executeBatch();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            System.out.println("Skipping insert...");
        }

        dbConnection.commit();
    }

    public List<Info> getUser() throws SQLException
    {

        Statement stmt = dbConnection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CARS");
        List<Info> users = new ArrayList<Info>();

        try
        {
            while (rs.next())
            {
                users.add(new Info(rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getInt(4), new Date(rs.getDate(5).getTime())));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        }
        return users;
    }
}
```

My problem in I can't to write and read in the database anything.
Errors in console:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nuodb.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at testPackage.CarServlet.doGet(CarServlet.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How to fix it?

Comment: You need to ensure this library is available when you run you application, just like you would for any other JAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the NuoDB JDBC jar is not in your classpath.

The [NuoDB documentation](http://doc.nuodb.com/display/doc/JDBC+Connections) states that it is located under the directory where NuoDB is install, under a subdirectory named `jar`.

You must either add that location to your web application class path (assuming your tomcat is on the same machine as your database), or copy the jar over to where tomcat will be able to find it, together with all the other jars you are using.